# What do you have to name an Eevee for it to evolve into a Umbreon?

Tags: pokemon-go

What do I name an Eevee to make it evolve into a Umbreon?

Answer (score 10):

You rename your Eevee into Tamao.

[Source](http://heavy.com/games/2017/02/pokemon-go-how-to-evolve-eevee-into-umbreon-espeon-evolution-eeveelutions-names-rename-tamao-sakura/)